# Error PhpMyAdmin la base de datos falla

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Me encuentro en un problema extraño
My base de datos en myphpadmin me muestra el siguiente error :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Trate de importar el respaldo de mi anterior tabla donde (correctamente mostro tabla repetida) pero igual mente mente causo errores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es muy extraño ya que reinstale my xampp y el error persiste, pienso que será algo relacionado con alguna carpeta faltante .Si alguien se a encontrado con este problema podría aconsejarme?

Comment: ¿Desde tu mysql si te puedes conectar con el usuario y contraseña que tienes configurado para el phpmyadmin?

Comment: hola M. Gress, no tiene contraseña el usuario es root y es el error que se ve constante una y otra ves :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que indican los mensajes de error, las credenciales de usuario establecidas en el fichero de configuración **c:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php** no son correctas.

Debes comprobar que los valores de las siguientes lineas coincidan con los establecidos en tu phpMyAdmin en Cuentas e Usuario

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';

Si tras esta comprobación el problema persiste es probable que haya un segundo servidor en tu computadora resolviendo por el mismo puerto en localhost.

Espero te sirva de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: ya lo intente y el problema persiste, creo que tengo en esta pc otro servidor como tu mencionas. hay manera de localizar este server y cerrarlo? o cambiar de puerto ?

Comment: Desde luego revisa en el panel de control que programas tienes instalados, es muy común que el conflicto lo cause una instalación de SQLServer. Chequea en el administrador de tareas que programas se ejecutan al inicio del sistema y como último recurso en el archivo de configuración httpd.conf, puedes cambiar el puerto de escucha de 80 a 8080 en las siguientes lineas: Listen 80. ServerName localhost:80. Para despues acceder por el navegador vía http://localhost:8080/phpMyAdmin

Comment: me acavas de resolver la pregunta muchas gracias, si e estado teniendo este problema (ya haciendo memoria ) desde que comenze a trabajar con SQL server , como e estado trabajando directamente en operacion no le preste mucha atencion a my xampp , y hoy que e tratado de adelantar algunas cosas en local me propuse solucionar el problema pero creo que es cosa de simplemente cerrar SQL server gracias  !!!

Answer (score 1):

Ve a la carpeta xampp y ve a phpMyAdmin, por defecto:

```
C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin
```

abre el archivo `config.inc` con cualquier editor de texto, busca las siguientes lineas y las reemplazas por `http`:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp'; //cambia tcp por http.
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config'; //cambia config por http.
```

Deben quedarte así:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'http';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
```

Reinicias xampp y listo, comenta los resultados. :)